# How can I run an UWP app on foreground at startup?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I'm trying to solve a problem related to run an UWP app on top at startup (with Winodws 10).

I already put the app in the autorun applications but it always runs in background (the application is opened and if I click on the icon in the application bar I can see it). Unfortunately, I would like that it runs automatically on top.

How can I solve it?

Comment: make it fullscreen

Comment: already done but it does not solve the problem....but thanks

Comment: This behavior is by design. By starting minimized it puts the user in control of the app's behavior. What were you trying to do? It is likely that there is a very specific reason that the you want the app to start as a window and not minimized. If we could understand what this particular scenario is we might be able to recommend a different or better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Xavier Xie` We are also facing the same problem, what we are trying to build is a Windows 10 IoT machine that displays latest contents in fullscreen from a server automatically whenever the machine is started up / restart. Tried with StartupTask but it only brings up the App minimized / suspended at Windows startup.

The only way workaround for now is to drag a shortcut link of the installed UWP App into the startup folder. (type "shell:startup" in Explorer) Not as elegant and automatic but it works.